# Django Url NoReverseMatch, reverse with key arguments not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

I have a trouble with URl mapping. I want that title of the post to be in the url and have NoReverseMatch error when trying to do this.

Here is app/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import PostsListView, PostDetailView

app_name = 'era'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostsListView.as_view(), name='posts_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<title>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view, 
    name='post_details')
]
```

app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post


class PostsListView(ListView):
    model = Post


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_details'
    template_name = 'era/post_details.html'
```

and finally era/post_list.html

```
{% extends 'era/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in post_list %}
    <div class="post-block" style="width: 27%;float: left; margin: 3%; background-color: rgba(169, 169,169,0.5); padding: 2%; border-radius: 15px">
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <br>
        {{ post.image_title }}
        <br>
        {{ post.short_description }}
        <br><br>
        <a href="{% url 'era:post_details' title=post.title %}" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">Read more</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Will be very gratefull for help!

Comment: Does your title consist of multiple words separated by spaces? If so it won't match `[\w-]+`. In any case, titles are not really suitable for use in URLs; that's why we have slugs.

Comment: yes, as example I was using 'Lil Peep dead'

Comment: slugs? how to use them? I need to make slug field in the model?